# Excel Add in - Refresh only my custom functions in a specific sheet

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, custom-functions-excel

I want to update custom formulas added my Excel add in. Using Application/worksheet.Caclulate() updates whole sheet, but I want to update only those cells which are using my formulas.

Comment: Before anyone marks it duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70219881/excel-add-in-refresh-all-custom-functions-in-a-specific-sheet answer in this question updates whole sheet, which I don't want to.

Comment: I can use Range/RangeArea Calculate Method, but for this I need to know which cells have my formulas. If it is possible to get cells having my formula, I can mark them dirty or directly call Calculate method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this, but what if you used the technique described in [Get formulas from a range of cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-ranges-set-get-values#get-formulas-from-a-range-of-cells) on the entire UsedRange of a worksheet. Then iterate through the returned array to find all the cells that have formulas matching one of yours. Then for each of those cells, call Calculate().

Comment: currently I am getting all cell from UsedRAnge and iterating them one by one and using string comparison to check if formula is implemented by my add in then mark this cell. After looping through entire range calculate my marked cells. However I am looking for some efficient solution.

Comment: I don't think the APIs provide a more efficient solution at this time.

Comment: agree with Rick. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The `Application` object provides a method to force an immediate recalculation. `Application.calculate(calculationType)` starts a manual recalculation based on the specified `calculationType`. The following values can be specified.

- `full`: Recalculate all formulas in all open workbooks, regardless of whether they have changed since the last recalculation.
- `fullRebuild`: Check dependent formulas, and then recalculate all formulas in all open workbooks, regardless of whether they have changed since the last recalculation.
- `recalculate`: Recalculate formulas that have changed (or been programmatically marked for recalculation) since the last calculation, and formulas dependent on them, in all active workbooks.

So, you could play with an argument to get the required piece recalculated.

Comment: As I mentioned in my question, Application.Calculate will also calculate those cells which are not using my custom formulas. I want to update only those cells which use my custom formula.